# Python Class List Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been given a task of implementing a Stack data structure and was given basic code that I had to work on. The aim of the task is to get the user to input data into the **stack** list and it is limited to 6 inputs.

When I run the test program, the menu of options appears as expected and I enter in the data and it returns `"True"`. However, it doesn't matter how much data I continually add in, it will always come back `"True"` and I'm not understanding why? After 6 elements have been added to the list, it should come back with an error message.

Main Program:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = list()
        self.StackSize = 5
        self.top = 0

    def push(self,data):
        #if there is room on the stack, add a new item to the end
        if self.top >= self.StackSize:
            return ("Error! Error! Unable to perform function! Stack is full! Stack is full!")
        self.stack.append(data)
        self.top +=1
        return True
    
    def pop(self):
        #if stack is not empty, return last item
        if self.top <= 0:
            return ("Error! Error! Unable to perform function! Stakc is empty! Stack is empty!")
        item = self.stack.pop()
        self.top -= 1
        return item

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.stack == []:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isFull(self):
        if len(self.stack) == StackSize:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def top(self):
        if self.stack:
            return self.stack[-1]
        else:
            return ("Stack is empty.")

    def getStack(self):
        return("Stack: " + self.stack)
```

Test Program:

```
from Stack import Stack

def main():

    s = Stack()

    print ("--- Menu of Options ---")
    print ("1: Add An Element To The Stack")
    print ("2: Remove The Top Element From The Stack")
    print ("3: Report Whether The Stack Is Empty")
    print ("4: Report Whether The Stack Is Full")
    print ("5: View The Top Element Of The Stack")
    print ("6: View The Entire Contents Of The Stack")
    print ("7: Exit Program")

    choice = input("\nPlease enter your choice: ")
    #Error handler to cope with an invalid choice

    while not choice in ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"):
        print("\nInvalid entry. Please select from the menu provided.")
        choice = input ("\nPlease enter your choice: ")

    if choice == "1":
        x = ""
        x = input("Add an element to the stack: ")
        print(s.push(x))
        main()

    elif choice == "2":
        print(s.pop())
        main()

    elif choice == "3":
        print(s.isEmpty())
        main()

    elif choice == "4":
        print(s.isFull())
        main()

    elif choice == "5":
        print(s.top())

    elif choice == "6":
        print(s.getStack())

    else:
        print ("Ending Program")
```

Comment: Use a loop instead of recursion. Calling ``main()`` recursively creates a new ``Stack`` instance each time.

Answer (score 0):

your `main()` method calls a new `main()` function. This creates a new `Stack` object. Essentially always resetting your stack. E.g. create the stack outside of your function.

```
s = Stack()

def main():
    # code as normal
```

Good luck with your homework

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
def main():

s = Stack()
```

When you call the main function, you create a new stack. And whenever you pick an option, you call the main function again.

```
elif choice == "2":
print(s.pop())
main()# here
```

This will create a new stack where the size will be 0 again. Since this is probably a learning task, I will just explain how you could fix this.

1. Put the stack in the parameter.
2. Create the stack outside of your function.
3. Use a while loop and not recursion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Each time that you select an acceptable option, you always call `main()`. By doing this, you are instantiating another `Stack` object which is, by definition, empty. Since you continue calling `main()`, your stack will never be full, but you'll have a `numMainCalls` number of `Stack`s each one with at most `1` element.

I suggest you define a main function that calls a subroutine in which you can cycle by passing the `Stack` object:

```
def main:
    s = Stack()
    print ("--- Menu of Options ---")
    print ("1: Add An Element To The Stack")
    print ("2: Remove The Top Element From The Stack")
    print ("3: Report Whether The Stack Is Empty")
    print ("4: Report Whether The Stack Is Full")
    print ("5: View The Top Element Of The Stack")
    print ("6: View The Entire Contents Of The Stack")
    print ("7: Exit Program")

    choice = input("\nPlease enter your choice: ")

    while True:
        choice = input("\nPlease enter your choice: ")
        execute_subroutine(s, choice)
        if choice == "7":
            break


def execute_subroutine(s, choice):
    if choice not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]:
        print("\nInvalid entry. Please select from the menu provided.")
    else:
        if choice == "1":
            x = ""
            x = input("Add an element to the stack: ")
            print(s.push(x))

        elif choice == "2":
            print(s.pop())

        elif choice == "3":
            print(s.isEmpty())

        elif choice == "4":
            print(s.isFull())

        elif choice == "5":
            print(s.top())

        elif choice == "6":
            print(s.getStack())

        else:
            print ("Ending Program")
```

this way you should be able to get what you want. Please note that there might be some minor issues with my code since at the moment I can't test it. Anyway, it should be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, it is greatly appreciated!